# My single.php page skips the first div tag

Tags: php, html, single

I'm currently styling my single.php file and for some reason when compiled the page completely skips the first  tag yet prints everything else afterwards, including the `<h1>` tag in the first `<div>`. The only fix I have produced at the moment is placing a blank `<div>` tag before `<div class="page-header mb-5">` in order to print and therefore see the styling however I feel that there is just a bug with my code and don't really want to have to rely on a blank `<div>` as a fix.

Any help?

```
<?php get_header();?>

<div class="page-header mb-5">
   <h1 class="text-center"><?php the_title();?></h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
      <?php the_content();?>
   <?php endwhile; endif;?>
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Your loop looks ok but could be simplified. It sounds to me that your content have missing <div> inside or something related. You could confirm by comment out `// the_content();` to see when there is no content, is the structure alright. If so, then you need to confirm the content.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the OP. Everything from the first <h1> tag is being compiled. However the line before that <div class="page-header mb-5"> is not. Therefore no styling is present when I go to visit the page as in the browser the body starts with the <h1> tag.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the url? Or is it only a localhost copy? We need some more information about it before we could suggest solutions.

Comment: It's a localhost, sorry :/

Comment: Then I suggest you replace the php code with static content. This techniques may help you to sort out which part have problem and pinpoint that part to resolve.

Comment: Okay, I feel stupid! Turns out the body tag wasn't closed in my header.php file - thank you for the help on this!

Comment: Can you post the code from “header.php” as well?

Comment: @Josh Glad that it helps. Happy coding. So post your header.php if possible (partial is ok or the problematic part) for reference that the future audience could learn and refer.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not officially answered the question, it is a suggested debugging technique for future audience to see how to resolve the related problem:

If you ever meet such situation. Then most likely there is some tag(s) is(are) missing creating such `cascading effect`. So

- could try to hide the content output first to see if it is the html inside the content creating issues.
- output the code piece by piece by replacing content with static content, and then add part by part to find out which produces missing tag(s) effect

After spotting out which part(s) could reduce time and effort to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://use.typekit.net/xaw5ryt.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Josh Birch Design</title>

    <?php wp_head();?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class();?>>
```

So I need new glasses! Turns out I was missing a closing tag on the `<body>`!

Thanks to those that contributed!

Edited: A notes for future audience:
Please also refer to the following suggested debugging technique in case of such issue which might help to find out the reason.